# Getting TIMEOUT error , when the SMS recieved using SMS_RETRIEVER_API consent API

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sms

I registered the receiver for SMS consent API and when received the sms below given broadcast `onReceive()` was not called, but after some time, always got `"CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT"`

```
private final BroadcastReceiver smsVerificationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                Status smsRetrieverStatus = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);

                switch (smsRetrieverStatus.getStatusCode()) {
                    case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // Get consent intent
                        Intent consentIntent = extras.getParcelable(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(consentIntent, SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST)
                        break;

                    case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:
                        // Time out occurred, handle the error.
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Kindly help me with this why and when it happens

when we receive sms, the broadcast receiver method should call and it will give the `CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS`